# Trying to create a control class for multiple form windows

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form window that has a button, which on click creates an instance of a different form window and launches it. Something like this:

```
private void button_onclick(stuff)
{
    form f = new form2;
    form2.showdialog();
}
```

This form2 has a similar button that launches form3, and so one.

What I would like to do is to create an instance of all my forms in the first from window. I would like to show the first form, have it deactivate but not close, return a value, and then show another one. I am trying to facilitate a "next button" and "back button". In particular, I want to make the back button return to the same instance of the form that called it. I am having a problem because the ShowDialog method I am using suspends the calling form until the called form closes. I want to return to the calling form without closing it, preferable with some kind of return value so I can use some logic to determine what happens next.

Some pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
form2;
form3;
form4;

while (form1 not closed)
{
    int test;
    test = form2.method();

    switch test
    {
    case test == 1  
    test = form3.method(); break;
    case test == 2
    test = form4.method(); break;
    .
    .
    .
} //end of while loop
```

I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: What about using `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` and then use the [Hide method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It looks like you want something like a `Wizzard dialog (next and previous step)` which could be made easier using UserControls and one form instead of many forms.

Answer (score 0):

Consider showing/hiding container controls on a single form, rather than different forms. Also, check out some of these examples online for ideas on how to implement back/next:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4005/A-NET-Wizard-control